# Get half bytes from a byte

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I have a SHA-512 generated byte array from some bytes.

`484c1514b468429967aa0c8e2ab6d99c14e7cd4a45605cb834ebfd3612a0cc9184510d8d0a9c92e636d82c065fa2db0e05ef5c2518153a6c4ca9eebbe8d7b475`

When I iterate like below;

```
for(byte x = 0; x < s512in.length; x++){
    System.out.println(String.format("%02X ", s512in[x]) + " );
}
```

I can get 48,4C,15.... but I want to get 4,8,4,C... from the byte array. How can I get that without converting to Strings?

Comment: What is the declared type of `s512in`?

Comment: @KirillK Err, a byte array?

Comment: Check if McDowell's answer helps. If not, please publish your code including the part of gettig s512in

Comment: @KirillK He has published his code, and he has stated that he has a byte array resulting from SHA-512 generation. Nothing else required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
byte[] data = "nibbles".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
for(byte b : data) {
    int high = (b & 0xf0) >> 4;
    int low = b & 0xf;
    System.out.format("%x%n", high);
    System.out.format("%x%n", low);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use as following.

```
    try {

        byte[] data = "nibbles".getBytes("UTF-8");
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            String temp = Integer.toString((data[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                    .substring(1);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't even compile, and wouldn't print nibbles if it did.

Comment: This is the same as I have posted down with the question though!

Comment: Edit still doesn't print 4,8,4,C,... as required. Suggest you test next time.